# Regex: Identify phone numbers in different formats

Tags: c#, regex

I have a website that people write jokes there. users can send jokes they like to their (or their friends) phones as sms. and the sender of the joke  (who has added the joke to the site) displayed below it:

**Joke #12234



this is the body
 of the joke



sender: John**

some times people use their phone numbers as the sender name, that is not allowed in public. I want to determine if there is a phone number in the sender name to be able to censor it. I assume any number bigger than 6 digits as a phone number. but the problem is that user might separate the numbers like:

**1234567890 should become 1234XXX7890

123 456 7890 should become 123 XXX 7890

123-456-7890

123456-7890**

and so on. any of the forms similar to above formats should be censored. I tried removing non numeric characters and then use regular expressions but the problem is then it also fetches:

**john23 peterson12345**

can anyone offer a better way?

Comment: Don't remove all non-numeric characters, but only hyphens, brackets and whitespaces

Comment: I guess, you should do all the restrictions on the client side thru JavaScript or HTML5, if it has elements, which allows numbers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all the formatting, replace

```
(\d{3}[-\s()]*)\d{3}([-\s()]*\d{4})
```

with

```
$1XXX$2
```

To further constrain for 10-digit numbers (*i.e.* disallow additional numbers immediately before and after), use negative lookaround assertions:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3}[-\s()]*)\d{3}([-\s()]*\d{4})(?!\d)
^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
```

Finally, what if typos lead users to insert space or symbols between groups, e.g. `(123)45 6-7890`? To catch these too, do the following:

```
(?<!\d)((?:\d[-\s()]*){3})(?:\d[-\s()]*){3}((?:\d[-\s()]*){4})(?!\d)
```

This may, however, catch "too much," e.g. `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0`. You will have to determine what balance you want to strike.

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem is as I said, phone numbers can be 7 to 11 digits. this code works for only 10.

Answer (score 0):

because of a lot of phone number format in this world, you can use this regex to identify any phone number. `^[0-9-+s()]*$`